# Find all customers that did business with all three companies

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a transactions table that contains customer names and the company they did business. There are three different company that the customers could have done business with A, B, C. How would I query for only customers that have done business with all three customers before?

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/817Cq.png)

A query that would only return Jack.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select [Customer Name]
from t
where Company in ("A", "B", "C")
group by [Customer Name]
having count(*) = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the records are unique by Customer Name / Company, you can use @GordonLinoff's answer, otherwise ensure they are unique with a subquery:

```
select [Customer Name]
from (select distinct [Customer Name], Company
      from t
      where Company in ("A", "B", "C")) x
group by [Customer Name]
having count(*) = 3;
```